# a sequence {xn} of real numbers is contractive if ∃ a constant C > 0, 0 < C < 1, such that |xn+1 − xn| ≤ C|xn − xn−1| for all n ∈ N.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We say that a sequence {xn} of real numbers is contractive if ∃ a constant
C > 0, 0 < C < 1, such that
|xn+1 − xn| ≤ C|xn − xn−1|

for all n ∈ N. Answer the following:
Show that every contractive sequence is convergent.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see that $ x_{n+1}- x_n \le c|x_n-x_{n-1}|
                          \le c^2|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|
                           \le ...
                           \le c^{n-1}|x_2-x_1|$
Let m>n
Then$ |u_m-u_n|\le|u_m -u_{m-1}|+...+|u_{n+1}-u_n|
                             \le|u_2-u_1|\{c^{m-3}+c^{m-4}+...+c^{n-2}\}
                             \le|u_2-u_1|c^{n-2}.\frac{1-c^{m-n-1}}{1-c}
                             \le\frac{c^n-2}{1-c}|u_2-u_1|$
 Let$\epsilon >0$, Since$0 \lt c\lt1$,the sequence $\{c_{n-2}\}$ is a convergent sequence.Therefore there exists a natural number P such that 
$$\frac{c^{n-1}}{1-c}|u_2-u_1|\lt\epsilon$$ for all m,n$\gt P$ It follows that $|u_m-u_n|\lt\epsilon$ for all m,n $\gt P$ and this proves that,$\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and it's convergent.